# Does Java optimize method calls via an interface which has a single implementor marked as final?

Tags: java, performance

If I have a reference to a class and invoke a method on it, and the class or the method is final, my understanding is that the compiler or the JVM would replace the dynamic dispatch with a cheaper static dispatch since it can determine exactly which version would be invoked.

However, what if I have a reference to an interface, and the interface currently has only a single implementor, and that implementor is final or the method is final in that implementor, can the JVM figure that out at runtime and optimize these calls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Insert Knuth quote here about optimization.)

See [Wikis Home  > HotSpot Internals for OpenJDK > PerformanceTechniques](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques).

> - Methods are often inlined. This increases the compiler's "horizon" of
>     optimization.
> - Static, private, final, and/or "special" invocations are easy to
>     inline.
> - Virtual (and interface) invocations are often demoted to "special"
>     invocations, if the class hierarchy
>     permits it. A dependency is registered
>     in case further class loading spoils
>     things.
> - Virtual (and interface) invocations with a lopsided type profile are
>     compiled with an optimistic check in
>     favor of the historically common type
>     (or two types).

There are some interesting links from [Inlining](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Inlining).

Comment: +1. You answered before I could and with a better link than I could have provided.  From my reading, the JVM can definitely make a non-virtual call when there is no reason from classes loaded currently to require a virtual call.  The nice thing about the Java and .NET VMs is that code can be recompiled when conditions change, such as a class being loaded that now required a method to be virtual.  This allows more aggressive optimizations.

Comment: The link is dead. This is the new [one](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Home).

Comment: The new link is also dead.  Here is the new one on the [openjdk wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the JVM can in-line up to two methods, the methods doesn't have to be final.  It can do this if the methods are small and called often. If your code calls three or more methods, only the most commonly called methods will be invoked.

Note 1: The JVM does care how many implementations there are, only how many are actually called.

Note 2: The JVM can inline methods which didn't exist at compile time, its only the code available at runtime which matters.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Virtual Machine as of today does not care for the "final" keyword anymore (only for class assertions). Everything is considered final, unless a class is loaded which overrides the specified function, or provides another implementation of it in case of an interface.

This results in multiple compilations of code if classes are loaded dynamically at runtime after the JIT compiler has already compiled something which it thought of as being final, but the gains seem to be wotrth the hassle.

I don't have a link to the paper about it, but I read it some weeks ago (and maybe its just in Java 7 like this).

Answer (score -2):

The JIT-compiler cannot do this, since it is quite common to create proxies for interfaces at runtime, so the JIT-compiler can never be sure that there won't be a dynamic proxy that implements a certain interface.

Comment: Actually, the JIT compiler can optimize with certain assumptions and then de-optimize if those assumptions are later found to be invalid.